# Why didn't the Clones kill Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

In Revenge of the Sith, Palpatine orders clone commanders to execute 66 which is to kill the Jedi as their are now traitors to the Republic but why didn't the Clones kill Anakin since he is a Jedi.

Comment: Because when Palpatine gave the order, Anakin was no longer a Jedi, but he had turned to the Dark Side...